# Custom post type menu disappeared

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am experiencing a strange issue.

I created a custom post type but for some reason it's not showing in the admin menu and when I am trying to access that page via url(edit.php?post_type=study_class) it says 'You donot have permission to access this page'

Here is the code

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_study_class');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_study_class() {
register_post_type('study_class', array(
'label' => 'Study Class',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'study_class',
'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_study_class', 
          'read_post' => 'read_study_class' ,
          'delete_post' => 'delete_study_class', 
          'edit_posts' => 'edit_study_class' ,
          'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_study_class', 
          'publish_posts' => 'publish_study_class' ,
          'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_study_class', 
          'read' => 'read',           
          'delete_posts' => 'delete_study_class', 
          'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_study_class', 
          'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_study_class', 
          'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_study_class', 
          'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_study_class', 
          'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_study_class', 
      ),
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'study_class', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Study Class',
  'singular_name' => 'Study Class',
  'menu_name' => 'Study Class',
  'add_new' => 'Add New Study Class',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add new Study Class',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Study Class',
  'new_item' => 'New Study Class',
  'view' => 'View Study Class',
  'view_item' => 'View  Study Class',
  'search_items' => 'Search  Study Class',
  'not_found' => ' Study Class not found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => ' Study Class not found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent  Study Class',
)
) );
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'capability_type' => 'post',

Comment: I tried with that but still not showing up.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters set 'capabilities' from capability type

Comment: Did it before but still can't get the menu in sidebar.

Comment: Remove `capabilities`, `cability_type` and `map_meta_cap` parameters in order to switch back to defaults.

Comment: @vard you are the God....I wasted 4 hrs since morning. Now please let me know what was the exact reason.

Comment: Please use it as an answer so that I can select/vote it.

Comment: @Raj Just did it. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `capabilities`, `capability_type` and `map_meta_cap` in order to switch back to default Wordpress post capabilities.

What you was doing was first to set a custom capability type named `study_class` - which isn't defined. Wordpress is using first the `capability_type` to build the capabilities object, then override with the capabilities set with the `capabilities` parameter. From the wordpress codex :

> The 'capability_type' parameter is used as a base to construct
>   capabilities unless they are explicitly set with the 'capabilities'
>   parameter.

Then you were sending an array of capabilities relating to the same custom capability type - which is kind of a duplicate. And as extension, the capability names were wrong, because Wordpress is looking for plurials in some cases:

```
[cap] => stdClass Object
(
    // Meta capabilities

    [edit_post]      => "edit_{$capability_type}"
    [read_post]      => "read_{$capability_type}"
    [delete_post]        => "delete_{$capability_type}"

    // Primitive capabilities used outside of map_meta_cap():

    [edit_posts]         => "edit_{$capability_type}s"
    [edit_others_posts]  => "edit_others_{$capability_type}s"
    [publish_posts]      => "publish_{$capability_type}s"
    [read_private_posts]     => "read_private_{$capability_type}s"

    // Primitive capabilities used within map_meta_cap():

    [read]                   => "read",
    [delete_posts]           => "delete_{$capability_type}s"
    [delete_private_posts]   => "delete_private_{$capability_type}s"
    [delete_published_posts] => "delete_published_{$capability_type}s"
    [delete_others_posts]    => "delete_others_{$capability_type}s"
    [edit_private_posts]     => "edit_private_{$capability_type}s"
    [edit_published_posts]   => "edit_published_{$capability_type}s"
    [create_posts]           => "edit_{$capability_type}s"
)
```

To have this working you would have need to [create this capability type](http://www.wpmayor.com/roles-capabilities-wordpress/) first.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a ton for this help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on the capabilities, you do not have such capabilities so you can not see or edit the post type.
Try to remove the capabilities and capability_type.

Comment: Mmh how this add any more informations to the answer I wrote 15min ago?

Comment: Sorry i did not saw your answer